# SS2008 Select tables with incremental names in a loop

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, loops

I'm running SQL Server 2008. I need to query tables which have incremental names.  The structure of these tables are exactly the same and I need to pull data from all of them (~50) tables. The tables' naming convention is as follows:  Break1, Break2, Break3, etc.  I am currently looping the data with the query below, but the problem lies in that the report generated leaves a gap between each set of data.  So, I have to throw into Excel, remove the spaces and put them all together into one data set.  Is there a better way of grabbing the data so that it is free of gaps?  My thoughts were to create a temp table and insert the data from each loop into it, but that's a bit over my head. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Query Example:

```
DECLARE @zone integer

DECLARE ZoneCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT ZoneID 
FROM Zone 
ORDER BY  ZoneID
OPEN ZoneCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM ZoneCursor into @zone

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    EXEC(' SELECT 
    CONVERT(smallint, '''+ @zone+''')  as ZoneID')
    ...
    FROM BREAK'+ @ZONE +' B (NOLOCK) 

    FETCH NEXT FROM ZoneCursor into @zone
  END
  CLOSE ZoneCursor
```

Example of Results:

```
ZoneID  Zone    NetworkID   Network Break_Date  Break_Time
------  ------- ---------   ------- --------------  --------------------------------
(0 row(s) affected)             

ZoneID  Zone    NetworkID   Network Break_Date  Break_Time
------  ------  ---------   ------- --------------  --------------------------------
2   ALPHARETTA-2538 1   CNN 4/1/2013    0:15:00
2   ALPHARETTA-2538 1   CNN 4/1/2013    0:15:00

ZoneID  Zone    NetworkID   Network Break_Date  Break_Time
------  ------- ---------   ------- --------------  --------------------------------
3   NEWTON-5491 1   CNN 4/1/2013    0:15:00
3   NEWTON-5491 1   CNN 4/1/2013    0:15:00
```

Comment: Have you looked into the UNION statement?  You could use that to join each query into one large query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options that come to mind.  The first is the UNION operator which would allow you to join everything into a single query:

```
SELECT ZONEID FROM BREAK1 (NOLOCK) 
UNION
SELECT ZONEID FROM BREAK2 (NOLOCK)
```

The second option is to create a temp table, select into that, then at the end of your loop, select out of it.

```
DECLARE @RESULTS TABLE ( ZONEID INT )
INSERT INTO @RESULTS SELECT ZONEID FROM BREAK1
INSERT INTO @RESULTS SELECT ZONEID FROM BREAK2
SELECT ZONEID FROM @RESULTS
```

Since you are doing this in a loop using EXEC statements, if you go with the UNION route, then you can just build a large select string and fire a single EXEC.  If you go the second route, then generate the temp table prior to your loop and select out of it after the loop closes.

Comment: The guts to the select statements are rather large, so I believe a UNION would be very large considering I'm also hitting around 50 tables.  I'd probably crash the system.  However, your 2nd Option is a great one, so thank you!  I will try it and hopefully it works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes insert the records as you go into a temp table, then select the whole temp table at the end?

First, before the cursor, create the temp table structure with create table. Temp tables begin with #, but otherwise the create statement is exactly teh same.

Then add the insert part to the dynamic SQl you have (inserts can use a select statment instead of a values statemenet).  Since you are now inserting insetead of selecting, you will return no results. So after the cursor, you will need to select * from the temp table.

(Of course, I have to say that this is a poor database design. Is it possible to use one table instead? Or at least create a view with all these tables and adjust the view when new tables are added?)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I concur, the database is not setup in the most efficient manner. However, that's how it was designed by the vendor, so I am unable to make and changes.  Only pull data from them.